# how to copy all code in vim with invalid register name?

Tags: vim, text-editors, copy-paste, paste, copy

I'm trying to select all the code in my vim editor in a putty session on my windows 10 and paste it on notepad in windows 10.

once I get into vim with terminal command vim code.s on ubuntu I've tried the widely used `:%y+` but get an error saying invalid registry name so its not possible to do that on ubuntu.  If any one know how to please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use of the clipboard on Linux requires the *X server*, so you'd need such on your Windows system (e.g. Cygwin-X), and start the ssh session with X forwarding (`ssh -X`). As evidenced by the many related questions here, this is a hassle to set up.

As a pragmatic quick workaround, you can

1. In Vim, write the selection / selected lines (e.g. with `:{range}write /tmp/file`) to the local (Ubuntu) file system
2. Use another PuTTY session to `pscp` that file to your Windows box.
3. Copy the file to the clipboard / directly insert its contents in a text editor.
4. (Remove the temp files.)

For just a few lines, selection with the mouse inside the PuTTY window is the fastest, but beware of changes in line breaks, whitespace, `:set number` and other complications.